# How bumblebee Nvidia works in Ubuntu?

Tags: graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, nvidia-prime

As far as I know `bumblebee` enables `nvidia gpu` when a selected client is running or run with `optirun`. But in wiki page `Bumblebee` mentioned the following line.

```
Using Bumblebee, you can use your NVIDIA card for rendering graphics which will be displayed using the Intel card
```

By this line what do exactly they mean? Is selected client rendered by `Nvidia GPU`(computation) then transferred to `Intel GPU`(to display)? Is `nvidia-prime` doing the same thing??

Comment: It's simple: bumblebee doesn't work lol... I mean, seriously. I've tryed everything, my optimus notebook simply won't work on Linux no matter how much I try.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. Nvidia Optimus technology works this way. Rendered by Nvidia or Intel and displayed by Intel.